# How best to make iterators for a plain array within a unique_ptr in C++11?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, iterator, unique-ptr

I want to use the richness of <iterator> with arrays held by unique_ptr.
Here's the code I'd like to write ajuxt the code I am currently obliged to write:

```
void question() {
 const int len = 10;
 int a[len];
 unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[len]);

 // i can do this with a bare array
 for_each(begin(a), end(a), [](int& v) { v = 0; });

 // but this doesn't compile cuz unique_ptr<T[]> doesn't implement dereference
 //  for_each(begin(*p), end(*p), [](int& v) { v = 0; });

 // this works, but ugly, and begin() and end() are not abstracted.
 for_each(&p[0], &p[len], [](int& v) { v = 0; });

 // how best to make iterators for an array within a unique_ptr?
}
```

Or might I be much better off using a container class instead of an array?

**ELABORATION:**

My full use case is a Buffer object that contains a raw array of audio samples that will be passed to an audio device. The length of the array is determined at Buffer construction and then remains fixed.

I'm not using a container class because the data must be contiguous in memory. But I want to iterate over the buffer to fill it with data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iterator>

using namespace::std;

struct Buffer {
 unique_ptr<double[]> buf;
 size_t len;
 int frameRate;
 Buffer(size_t len) : buf(new double[len]), len(len) {}
};

class Osc {
 double phase, freq;
public:
 Osc(double phase, double freq) : phase(phase), freq(freq) {}
 void fill(Buffer& b) {
  double ph = phase;
  for_each(b.buf.get(), next(b.buf.get(), b.len), [&ph, &b](double& d) {
   d = sin(ph);
   ph += 1.0/b.frameRate;
  });
 }
};

int main() {
 Buffer buf(100);
 Osc osc(0, 440);
 osc.fill(buf);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `len` is `const` then why do you need to dynamically allocate the array? If `len` isn't `const` then why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Comment: Personally, I would stick with `std::array` or `std::vector` (depending on the need for the structure to change size) and only use raw arrays when forced into it by an external forcing function (e.g., an external API).

Comment: @user657267 removing const breaks begin()/end() on my bare array. Why? Is there a type distinction between T[n] and T[const n]? Sorry, I don't know C++ very well.

Comment: @soliton_zero If the array is of a fixed size you do not need to dynamically allocate it with `new`, just use `int p[10];` / `std::array<int, 10> p;`. If it isn't fixed then use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @soliton_zero you're not happy with the answer provided below ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

void question() {
 const int len = 10;

 std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[len]);
 int x = 0;
 std::for_each(std::next(p.get(), 0), std::next(p.get(), len), [&](int& a) { a = ++x; }); // used std::next(p.get(), 0) instead of p.get().
 std::for_each(std::next(p.get(), 0), std::next(p.get(), len), [](int a) { std::cout << a << "\n" ;});

}

int main()
{
    question();
}
```

Comment: but why doesn't begin(p.get()) return an iterator?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin - go through the function overloads. There is no overload of `std::begin` that returns iterator of the pointer.

Comment: Just made an edit so that you get iterators for both start and end. This is just to satisfy your requirement of having iterator. As others have said, either use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of `std::unique_ptr`. You don't need to worry about the memory management or using them in STL algorithms

Comment: Why `std::next(p.get(), 0)` instead of `p.get()`? @soliton_zero `std::begin/end` are not specified to work with bare pointers, and `unique_ptr<T[]>` doesn't have member `begin/end` either since it doesn't store the size of the managed array. It's unclear what answer you're looking for exactly.

Comment: @Praetorian my initial code was p.get() itself. OP was insisting on being able to use `std::begin()` so I said ok you could use `std::next ` if you like but not `std::begin`.

Comment: Your earlier comment about *Just made an edit so that you get iterators for both start and end* seems to indicate you have a misunderstanding about the return value type of `std::next`. It returns the same category of *iterator* that you pass as the first argument, in this case `int *`. A bare `T *` is a perfectly good RandomAccessIterator, and in the code above there is no difference between writing `std::next(p.get(), 0)` / `p.get()` or `std::next(p.get(), len)` / `p.get() + len`.

Comment: @Praetorian I understand that they return the same type. Anyways, in my view this is just a question with no real requirement or use.

Comment: @Praetorian My earlier code has `std::for_each(p.get(), std::next(p.get(), len)...)` if I think that `std::next()` returns a different type here, how could I pass 2 different types to an algorithm that expects same type for begin and end ?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me :) I was only responding to the wording in your earlier comment which seemed to suggest that passing the `int *` through a NOP call to `next` made a difference. Anyway, clearly you don't have any such misunderstanding.

Comment: It's dawning on me that T[] is a different type than T[N], and T[] is merely T* and is not a collection. Therefore the concepts of begin() and end() don't apply to it.

Comment: Also I'm surprised to learn that std::vector's elements are guaranteed to be contiguous, so maybe it can double as an audio buffer.